# Can relay-compiler read the schema from an endpoint (http or https)?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, graphql-js, relayjs

Relay's ahead-of-time compilation generates new compiled artifacts. To be able to do that, it's necessary to pass the GraphQL schema path to its config file. My question is: **can that path be a URL? If not, what is the alternative way?** The documentation is very vague about that.

**Why do I need it to be a URL?**
My backend is in another service, so I have to find a way to access its schema. I was using the `graphql get-schema` command ─ which makes a local copy of the remote schema. But the `get-schema` command was deprecated in `graphql-cli@4`.

> get-schema is no longer available
> In previous versions, you were able to download the schema to the given path in schemaPath from >the URL given inside endpoint. In the new version, schema refers to the endpoint of the schema.
>
> If you use Prisma or any other tool that provides your schema under URL endpoint, you must >specify it using the following syntax in your configuration YAML:

**Source:** https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-cli/blob/a8fc4bc6376205b2c6ee077cc0acfcef0712b470/docs/MIGRATION.md#get-schema-is-no-longer-available

Since then, I can't find a easy way to sync the remote schema with my front-end project. Maybe the only alternative is to downgrade to `graphql-cli@3`?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `relay-config`, unlike `graphql-config`, does not accept a URL schema. It must be a local path.

So, you have to keep using a local schema. The `graphql-cli@4` migration guide explains how to download the schema since this functionality is not in the core of the package anymore:

> If you want to download the schema from this URL to your local file system, you will also need to install `codegen` plugin and its `schema-ast` plugin using the following command or its npm equivalent:
>
> ```
> yarn add @graphql-cli/codegen @graphql-codegen/schema-ast --dev
> ```
>
> After that, you can specify the output path of the local schema file:
>
> ```
> schema: http://localhost:4000/graphql
> extensions:
>   codegen:
>     generates:
>       ./schema.graphql:
>         plugins:
>           - schema-ast
> ```
>
> By running graphql codegen, the schema.graphql file is generated in the root path of your project.

**Source:** https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-cli/blob/a8fc4bc6376205b2c6ee077cc0acfcef0712b470/docs/MIGRATION.md#get-schema-is-no-longer-available